# Android setonclicklistener crashed

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, setonerrorlistener

I am trying to go back to previous activity after a linear layout or back button is touched however I am getting the nullpointer exception error even tough I have initialized the button and layout in onCreate method

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference

My Java file

```
package com.profile;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.R;

public class AboutActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);
        LinearLayout backlayout=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.back_button_linear_layout);
        ImageButton backButton=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.back_profile_btn);
        backlayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
        backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

My XML file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.profile.AboutActivity">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/back_profile_layout"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/back_profile_btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@color/transparentBackgroundPrimaryDark"
                android:maxHeight="20dp"
                android:maxWidth="20dp"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/back_100px" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="About"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.Space
        android:layout_width="10sp"
        android:layout_height="20sp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Terms"
        android:layout_width="345dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button_primary"
        android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Terms and Conditions"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        />
    <android.support.v4.widget.Space
        android:layout_width="10sp"
        android:layout_height="20sp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Data_policy"
        android:layout_width="345dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button_primary"
        android:color="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Data policy"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        />
    <android.support.v4.widget.Space
        android:layout_width="10sp"
        android:layout_height="20sp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Licences"
        android:layout_width="345dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button_primary"
        android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Licences"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        />
    <android.support.v4.widget.Space
        android:layout_width="10sp"
        android:layout_height="20sp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="209dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Version 1.1.1000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_weight="0.87" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'm a little bit confuse about correct compilation of this.

Comment: yeah i agree @SergeyShustikov, but it's possible that the id is present in some other layout? it compiles successfully in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
LinearLayout backlayout=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.back_button_linear_layout);
```

to this

```
LinearLayout backlayout=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.back_profile_layout);
```

because you are assign wrong `id` to `LinearLayout` that's why it give you `NullPointerExecption`.

and also Remove this `import com.R;` is not require.